# How to add multiple buttons in Jquery UI dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I would like to have more than one button. I tried to copy code between brackets but doesnt work.Ideas?

```
buttons: {

"Close": function() {
 $(this).dialog("close");

}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Create them using this format, `'button text': function() { }` with a comma inbetween, like this:

```
$("#mydialog").dialog({
  buttons: {
    'Confirm': function() {
       //do something
       $(this).dialog('close');
    },
    'Cancel': function() {
       $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Excellent solution for beginners like me. Thank you very much. I am always so confident to learn new technology; why because I know that stackoverflow can show answer to the problem I am facing...

Answer (score 5):

To add to this, the button array method is useful to know about as it exposes more functionality per button, such as adding icons and other per-button properties.  The points to note being the added square brackets around the set of buttons turning it into an array of buttons, and the extra curly braces around each button object.

```
$("#mydialog").dialog({
  buttons: [{
    text: 'Confirm',
    icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-check"
    },
    click: function() {
       //do something
       $(this).dialog('close');
    }},{
    text: 'Cancel',
    icons: {
        primary: "ui-icon-cancel"
    },
    click: function() {
       $(this).dialog('close');
    }
  }]
});
```