# jQuery Ui Dialog Buttons, How to add class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I found this answer on another thread..

[How to add multiple buttons in Jquery UI dialog box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512463/how-to-add-multiple-buttons-in-jquery-ui-dialog-box)

Using this syntax, how do you add class to a particular button?

```
 $("#mydialog").dialog({
      buttons: {
        'Confirm': function() {
           //do something
           $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        'Cancel': function() {
           $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: ...Laphroiag Whisky and a Cuban cigar.

Comment: @rockerest: You just made my day. Laphroiag 10 year single malt is my go to Scotch.

Comment: @bpeterson76 answered this as concisely as possible.  i18n folks know what to do to make the solution work for them.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's a great way to do this via the API, however you could add the classes in an event handler for [`create`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-create):

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    buttons: {
        'Confirm': function() {
            //do something
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        'Cancel': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    create:function () {
        $(this).closest(".ui-dialog")
            .find(".ui-button:first") // the first button
            .addClass("custom");
    }
});
```

If you wanted the second button, you could use:

```
$(this).closest(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-button").eq(1).addClass("custom") // The second button
```

The key is the `$(this).closest(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-button")`, which will select the buttons in your dialog. After that, you could apply any selector you want (including `:contains(...)` which might be useful if you want to select a button based on its text instead of its order).

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jjdtG/

Also note that the CSS selector for the style(s) you want to apply has to be more specific than jQueryUI's built-in selectors in order for the styling to be applied.

Comment: +1 This works great, but I used the `open` instead of `create` because I am opening and closing the same dialog a few times.

Comment: .dialog({dialogClass: "custom", ...}) is how it says to do it in the docs.

Comment: @popnoodles: This is a pretty old answer. That probably *is* the preferred way to do it nowadays.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker though still probably preferred if you want to just add the .ui-priority-primary class to one button. It'd be nice if the buttons just supported something like a buttonClass option you could pass in with the definition.

Comment: I think this need a correction, the first button,eq(0), is the X button used to close the dialog, so index = 1 is the second button.

Answer (score 91):

You Can add class to the button's in Dialog...by

```
$('#mydialog').dialog({
  buttons:{
    "send":{
      text:'Send',
      'class':'save'
    },
    "cancel":{
      text:'Cancel',
      'class':'cancel'
    }
  });
```

I think this will work for you. and you can find more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138291/jquery-dialog-save-cancel-button-styling).

Comment: You should change the word "className" for "class"

Comment: Although this works, it generates errors in many IDEs (like Netbeans), leading me to choose the above method(finding the buttons and adding the class) instead.

Comment: Is the errors indicating that `class` is reserved? You can wrap the word with quotes to avoid these errors if so.

Comment: I think it is the right approach but the class is added first to other jqueryui classes so the css rule would need !important

Comment: I think this should be marked as answer as it's the best solution.

Comment: this is definitely the best solution offered so far.

Comment: I'm getting "unexpected token )" in Chrome with this

Answer (score 48):

Hope it will help !

```
$("#mydialog").dialog({
          buttons: {
            'Confirm': function() {
               //do something
               $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            "Cancel": {
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    class: 'custom-class'
                }
          }
        });
```

Comment: upvoted for showing example of click, text, & class together.

Comment: This is helpful. Although I wish jquery would append the class, not inserted it first.

Answer (score 8):

Use the open event handler:

```
open: function(event) {
     $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:contains("Cancel")').addClass('cancelButton');
 }
```

Clean, simple, piece of cake!

Comment: Don't forget about i18n! This approach won't work if the website supports multiple languages

Comment: It could respect i18n if you replaced the string of the button with the value for the language.  You could also change your selector if need be.  i18n wasn't part of the OP's question.....and for most developers, it's largely an edge case.

Comment: @bpeterson76: Maybe most developers at Oracle, but outside of the US, i18n is a main concern... usually for US users who can't cope with sites that don't use their 'special' date format.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to LintonB, you can add all of the property attached to a button like style, id, etc...

```js
dialog_options.buttons = {
  'Modify': {
    click: function() {

      $(this).dialog('close');

      if (inputs.phone !== '') {
        inputs.phone.focus();
        inputs.phone[0].value = "";
      }
    },
    class: 'btn btn-labeled btn-warning',
    style: 'margin-right: 30px;',
    id: 'modificationId'
  },
  'Keep': {
    click: function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');

      _this.validatePhone(i);

    },
    class: 'btn btn-labeled btn-warning',
    id: 'conserverId'
  }
};
```