# JQuery UI - Change the button class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can someone explain how I can change the CSS class on the button, for the standard JQuery UI dialog widget?
My addClass() call is not working.

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $(this).addClass("btn");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Post your HTML, please.

Comment: maybe you'll find this helpful: [addClass in create function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702279/jquery-ui-dialog-buttons-how-to-add-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer what you meant to ask, "Can someone explain how I can change the CSS class **of a button** for the standard JQuery UI dialog widget" there are a few ways. This is the most self-contained.
Note that `'class'` is encapsulated with single quotes. This is because IE breaks if it's not.

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons:[
        {
            text: 'Ok', 
            'class': 'btn',
            click: function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Cancel', 
            'class': 'cancel',
            click: function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The dialogClass seems to be what you are looking for

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    dialogClass: 'btn',
    ...

});
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not affect the class attached to the button

Comment: That might be what you meant to ask instead of what you asked!

Comment: This IS a correct answer, just not complete. Your dialog now has a class name, you can navigate to the button you wish since you can now reference any child elements!