# i want to add id for a button in utils dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here I have my `Add to library` button. How can I add an `id` to it?

```
 Utils.dialog({
                            message: save_graph_canvassheet_html,
                            title: 'Add graph to canvas library',
                            buttons: {

                                'Add to library': function () {

                                    var form = $(this).closest('.content');

                                    var title = form.find('input[name="title"]').val()
                                    var date_option = form.find('input[name="date_option"]:checked').val()

                                    if (!title) {
                                        alert($.i18n._('Please enter a title'));
                                        return false;
                                    }

                                    Utils.status({
                                        id: 'add_canvas_sheet',
                                        text: 'Adding element to library'
                                    })
                                    graph_params.class_str = instrument_class_name;
                                    delete graph_params.graph_height;
                                    delete graph_params.graph_width;
                                    delete graph_params._;

                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: '/ajax/CanvasSheet/add_element',
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        async: false,
                                        data: {
                                            title: title,
                                            params: graph_params,
                                            type: 'graph',
                                            date_option: date_option
                                        },
                                        success: function (response) {
                                            if (response.success) {
                                                $('#canvassheets_dialog').trigger('refresh_elements');
                                            }

                                            Utils.status({
                                                id: 'add_canvas_sheet'
                                            })
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                            },
                            modal: false
                        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on LintonB's answer of this thread:

[jQuery Ui Dialog Buttons, How to add class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702279/jquery-ui-dialog-buttons-how-to-add-class)

I guess you can do something like this:

```
Utils.dialog({
    message: save_graph_canvassheet_html,
    title: 'Add graph to canvas library',
    buttons: {

        'Add to library': {
            click: function () {

            var form = $(this).closest('.content');

            var title = form.find('input[name="title"]').val()
            var date_option = form.find('input[name="date_option"]:checked').val()

            if (!title) {
                alert($.i18n._('Please enter a title'));
                return false;
            }
            },
            text: 'Add to library',
            id: 'buttonID'
         }
```

Comment: Im sorry I missed a "}" for close the function() in click, check the edited answer.

Comment: again am getting error, i added by full code here, :-( please help

Comment: Hi, if you want we can continue to check it in the next chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186515/i-want-to-add-id-for-a-button-in-utils-dialog

Comment: dont have much reputation,so not getting chat room

Comment: Sorry, I see your full code in your edited message but I see that you haven't edited using my answer. Can you please do it for see what could be the problem? Also, would be usefull to tell me what error are you getting.