# Multiple buttons in jquery ui dialog only one shows

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, jquery-ui-dialog

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/2eCUa/4/) is the fiddle. I have looked at the question '[How to add multiple buttons in Jquery UI dialog box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512463/how-to-add-multiple-buttons-in-jquery-ui-dialog-box)', but the methods mentioned there did not work. The accepted one was:

```
$("#mydialog").dialog({
    buttons: {
        'Confirm': function() {
            //do something
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        'Cancel': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

feel free to revise my fiddle and notify me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method in the question you linked does work. Your fiddle is incorrect. It has

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    modal: true,
    dialogClass: 'no-close',
    buttons: [{
        text:'OK',
        click: function () {
             $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        text:'Cancel',
        click: function () {
             location.reload();
        }
    }]
});
```

If you change this to the format shown in the question you linked

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
     modal: true,
     dialogClass: 'no-close',
     buttons: {
         'OK' : function () {
             $(this).dialog('close');
         },
         'Cancel' : function () {
             location.reload();
         }
     }
 });
```

you get two buttons.